HUD doesn't work correctly on RX-350 2024
The HUD Display on my rx350 doesn't seem to be working. I turned it on and increased the brightness. If I turn it off, I can see it display properly on the dashboard but when I turn it on, I don't see it display on the windshield. However, If you step out of the car and look below the windshield, you will see it as if it is inside the dashboard box (See image below)
NOTE: I bought this car with a damaged windshield but had it replaced.
I bought an rx350 2024 with a damaged windshield

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! :o)

When in the HUD menu using your steering wheel controls, use the up/down arrows to adjust the position of the display (left/right arrows should control brightness). More than likely the display is parked at a position which is outside of your view.
Generally, here are the instructions I got from the Google AI:

To adjust the head-up display (HUD) in a 2024 Lexus RX 350, you can do the following:



Press the HUD button on the left side of the steering wheel to turn it on
Press the Home button on the steering wheel
Use the left and right arrow buttons to display the Settings menu
Use the up and down arrows to highlight HUD Brightness/Position
Press the OK button to select it
Use the left and right arrows to adjust the brightness
Use the up and down arrows to adjust the position


